# Spotted a leak in UITextView delegate method. Confused about solution

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uitextview

I've got a problem with an UITextView and one of its delegate methods in my navigation based app:

```
- (BOOL)textView:aView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
```

I managed to limit the max length of text the user can input using the above method. But I'm using a leaky array for that matter I think.

The problem is: 
I want to save the amount of typed characters right in the very moment the user enters the last line of my textview. I then use that value to calculate the string length - which I compare to the textview's content size to set a limit. The code works fine - but since the method it's inside of is updating with every text input, I'm having trouble releasing the array in the right moment.

Here's some code:

```
if (numLines == 9)
{
    if (!numCharsArray) 
    {
        numCharsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:1]; // Stack trace gives this line 3,3% of the leak.
    }

    numChars = tView.text.length;
    NSNumber *number = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInteger:numChars]; // This line gets 77,3%.
    [numCharsArray addObject:number]; // This line gets the rest, 24,3%.
    [number release];

    startChars = [[numCharsArray objectAtIndex:0] integerValue];

    NSString *lastLine = [[NSString alloc]initWithString:[[tView text] substringFromIndex:startChars]];
    CGSize lineSize = [lastLine sizeWithFont:tView.font forWidth:tView.contentSize.width lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
    [lastLine release];

    if (range.length > text.length) 
    {
        return YES;
    }
    else if (numLines == 9 && lineSize.width >= tView.contentSize.width - 45)
    {
        return NO;
    }
}
else
{
    numCharsArray = nil;
    /* 
    if(numCharsArray)
    {
        [numCharsArray release];
    }
    */
}
```

I tried the out-commented statement above, but that gives me an app crash once I leave the last line of the textview. And as you can see in the code comments - without releasing the array I get a leak.

So how and where do I release that array correctly - keeping it safe while the user is on the last line?

Answer (score 1):

Just replace with

first one

```
numCharsArray = [NSMutableArray array]; // you do not need to release 
                                           //explicitly as its autorelease numberWithInt
```

second one

```
NSNumber *number = [NSNumber numberWithInt:numChars]; //autorelease

NSString *lastLine = [[tView text] substringFromIndex:startChars];
```

Comment: Thanks for the help m8! That just might work. Stupid me for not thinking of that! BUT actually I just got an idea of my own and rewrote the whole method. In the end I found a way without even using arrays & stuff ... ;) If you'd like I'll post it here. But since I'm new I'm not allowed to answer my own question for the next 6 hours. I'll do it then - if you're interested. Just tell me. And thanks again! :)

Comment: you can always use the pastebin(http://pastebin.com) and send us the link in your comment.

Comment: Oh. Didn't even know about that service ... ;) Here's the link: http://pastebin.com/BfJJnEbV - And thanks again. Maybe I should change my lastLine string to your version!

Comment: yeah let me know if it works with replace lastLine string to my version? In my answer i just improved your code a bit in well manner. :)